# TypeError: $.ajax is not a function at HTMLSelectElement

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem in my jquery (I think) and I'm not seeing the solution. I have 3 select boxs in html structure. The first one is populated by a sqlsrv query and the second one uses as ajax call based on the selection of the first one.

Till this point, is everything Ok.

Then, the third select box, I use another ajax call based on the selection of the second select box and does not work. Console log shows that "TypeError: $.ajax is not a function".

I don't understand because in the previous selections, it works.

Html Code:

```
<label for='cliente' class='mr-sm-2' style='font-size: 14px; margin-top: 15px;'>Cliente</label>
<select class='custom-select' id='cliente' name='cliente' style='font-size:12px;' required>
        <?php
        $sql= sqlsrv_query($conn,"Select no, nome from cl(nolock) where vendnm='".$utilizador."' 
        ");
         ?>
<option value=''>-- Select --</option>
<?php
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
echo "<option value='".$row['no']."'>".$row['nome']."</option>"; }
?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-6" style='text-align: left;'>
<label for='doc' class='mr-sm-2' style='font-size: 14px; margin-top: 15px;'>Document</label>
<select class='custom-select' id='doc' name='doc' style='font-size:12px;' required disabled>
<option value=''>-- Select --</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-4" style='text-align: left;'>
<label for='referencia' class='mr-sm-2' style='font-size: 14px; margin-top: 15px;'>Item</label>
<select class='custom-select' id='referencia' name='ref' style='font-size:12px;' required disabled>
<option value=0>-- Select --</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
    <script>

$(document).ready(function(){

          $("#cliente").change(function () {
    
            var cat = $("select[name=cliente]").val();
            $.ajax({
            url: 'docs.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{doc:cat},
          


              beforeSend: function(){
                $("#doc").css({'display':'block'});
                $("#doc").html("Carregando...");

                $('#doc').html('<option value="">-- Seleccione o doc.compra --</option>');
                $('#referencia').html('<option value="">-- Seleccione a referencia --</option>');

                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#doc").css({'display':'block'});
                    $("#doc").html(data); 
                },
                error: function(data)
                {
                    $("#doc").css({'display':'block'});
                    $("#doc").html("Houve um erro ao carregar");

                }
            });
            });

            $("#doc").change(function (){
            var deptid1 = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
            url: "refs.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{referencia:deptid1},

              beforeSend: function(){
                $("#referencia").css({'display':'block'});
                $("#referencia").html("Carregando...");
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#referencia").css({'display':'block'});
                    $("#referencia").html(data);
                },
                error: function(data)
                {
                    $("#referencia").css({'display':'block'});
                    $("#referencia").html("Houve um erro ao carregar");
                }
            });
            });

 
 });

</script>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Note:

If I cancel ajax on the second select box and use fixed options, the ajax call for the third selection box, works fine.

Help ?

Comment: tried checking the console for any other errors?

Comment: Please fix the formatting (and the indentation of your code/markup)

Comment: Using bootstrap with slim version of jQuery - it has no ajax inside?

Comment: Console Log errors:   tdatadevol.php:381 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (tdatadevol.php:381)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (VM569 jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (VM569 jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: Ajax is working well in the second select box. So, the question about the slim version of jQuery is not the point.

Comment: I think the problem occurs when the options of the second select box are called from an ajax call

Comment: It might help to show the HTML that the PHP generates so that we can more easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: When I dont use Ajax in the second select Box and use fixed options, the ajax call for the third select box is working. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `$` exists but `$.ajax` is not a function. For example, if you create an object and try to execute a member function that does not exist, you get a similar result. Example:

```
({}).ajax()
```

Now, your point is that it has been successfully executed. There are (obviously) two cases: you are either right or wrong. If you are wrong, then your starting point misleads you. So the first thing to check is whether the other $.ajax **really** works. A `console.log` in a callback should suffice for this text, like

```
console.log("success");
```

If you see that text, then it was successful. It is worth testing this, no matter how right (you think) you are to exclude misunderstandings of the situation.

Now, assuming that you are right when stating that the other call to the function worked, you will need to debug your code and add `$.ajax` to your watch, debug all your callbacks and everything. See when does your `$.ajax` becomes `undefined`. That's the moment when trouble happens. Probably `$` is overriden by something else, so it's also worth to do a

```
console.log($);
```

**AFTER** the error happened.